# Java - Log in as User or Admin? Inheritance

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

I have a log in system on my application that has a set of predefined users like so:

```
User user = new User("tommy", "tommy", false);
User user2 = new User("phil2", "phil2", false);
User user3 = new User("phil", "phil", true);
Admin admin = new Admin("benji", "benji", true);
```

These are then added to an array of users

```
userArray.add(user);...
```

which the logIn() method loops through and checks their credentials against when attempting to log in.

The users can log in as expected, but **how can I get the admin account to log in?** Note the admin is still a User, just a special type of user with a different menu when logged in. Currently the admin account isn't recognised as a user.

In my User class I have this: The Admin inherits from users since it is a user:

```
public class Admin extends User {           
    public Admin(String username, String password, boolean av) {
        super(username, password,av);
    }
```

LogIn() looks like this:

```
public void LogIn() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Welcome to the system \n Enter your Username and Password to continue \n Username: ");
    String temp = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(" Password: ");
    String temp2 = in.nextLine();

    //while(LOCount != 3){
    for (int i = 0; i < userArray.size(); i++) {
        if (userArray.get(i).CheckUsername(temp) && userArray.get(i).CheckPassword(temp2)) {
            // if(userArray.get(i) instanceof User.Admin){
            UserMenu();
```

Checkusername() & checkpassword() as requested:

```
public Boolean CheckPassword(String password) {         
    return this.password.equals(password);
}   

public Boolean CheckUsername(String username) {         
    return this.username.equals(username);
}
```

I'm new with inheritance so any help I would be grateful for, thanks!

Comment: show your logIn() code

Comment: I'll add it to the main question now. added

Comment: You're question is so strange, are you using JAAS?

Comment: Not using JAAS, what's confusing you? Sorry I find it hard to explain my questions sometimes.

Comment: Could you add code for `CheckUsername` and `CheckPassword` methods?

Comment: added CheckUsername & CheckPassword

Comment: why you are trying to achieve distinction between admin and user by creating different model? if you do this by adding privileges, your application will be more flexible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this.

Moving the login method to the user class allows you to to keep the logic and properties abstract. Overriding the login method in the Admin class allows you to do additional checks.

By calling `super.login();` the admin has the exact same authentication logic as a regular user. By performing additional checks using `final boolean isAuthorized = isAllowedToDoThis();` you can check if the Admin is allowed to perform said action.

Same thing for `getMenu();`. Since you override the implementation you can simply call `getMenu();` on an object and it will load either the user or admin menu depending on the type of object.

Note that this is just an abstract layout of how you could implement this.

```
public class User {

    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final boolean something;

    public User(String username, String password, boolean something) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.something = something;
    }

    public boolean login() {
        return correctPassword && correctUsername
    }

    private boolean correctPassword() { }
    private boolean correctUsername() { }

    public Menu getMenu() {
        // Return User menu
    }
}


public class Admin extends User {

    public Admin(String username, String password, boolean something) {
        super(username, password, something);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean login() {
        final boolean isAuthenticated = super.login();
        final boolean isAuthorized = isAllowedToDoThis();
        return isAuthenticated && isAuthorized;
    }

    private boolean isAllowedToDoThis() { }

    @Override
    public Menu getMenu() {
        // Return Admin menu
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,

When declaring 
Admin admin = newAdmin("ben", "ben", true);

It's not recognising the Admin class within User?

Comment: When declaring Admin admin = newAdmin("ben", "ben", true); It's not recognising the Admin class within User? 

Admin cannot be resolved to a type, so I tried to import it from the User class but when I do that it says the import user cannot be resolved?

Comment: I don't really get what you're saying, but be sure to move both User and Admin to their own class file. Secondly, the User and Admin classes should be public. If this doesn't help you I'd need more code to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid `instanceof`. You can do this:

```
public interface Menu {
    void show();    
}

public class UserMenu implements Menu {
  @Override
  public void show() {
    //show user menu
  }
}

public class AdminMenu implements Menu {
  @Override
  public void show() {
    //show admin menu
  }
}

public class User {

   private String username;
   private String password;

   public Menu getMenu() {
     return new UserMenu();
   }

   public boolean authenticate(String username, String pass) {
       return this.username.equals(username) && this.password.equals(pass); 
   }
   //getters & setters
}

public class Admin extends User {
   //Constructor
   @Override
   public Menu getMenu() {
     return new AdminMenu();
   }
}
```

And in your `logIn()` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userArray.size(); i++) {
    User user = userArray.get(i);
    if (user.authenticate(username, password)) {
        user.getMenu().show();
        //for look must finish, maybe with break?
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is genius, because it would work for both console and GUI applications! With some additions, you could handle the entire business logic associated with menu interaction, all in either the `Menu`s or the `User`s!